# Analytics Code Not Tracking after 24 hours

Tags: google-analytics

I've installed - and I believe I installed right - Google Analytics code yesterday. But still getting "not tracking" message and 0 stats. Can anyone check if there is something wrong?

I don't know if it's allowed to give urls. So, the website is my display name dot com if you want to check.

Here is my head code:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Babality - Oyunlar, Hileler, Combolar</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="flash oyun, unity oyunları, 3d oyunlar, flash oyunlar, tam ekran oyun, oyun hileleri, oyun comboları, oyun komboları">
<meta name="description" content="domain.com; kaliteli ve eğlenceli oyunların, popüler oyunlara ait hilelerin ve comboların bulunduğu bir web sitesidir.">
<link href="http://domain.com/tyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain.com/jss.js"></script>
<!-- analytics script -->
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-55572105-1', 'auto');
  ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script></head>
```

I've tried some websites that checks if anaytics code works. Every site I tried saw my analytics code working.

I've tried GA Debug extension on Chrome. Can't find any errors. 
I can see my code in my pages
I've tried Google Tag Assistant extension on Chrome. It found a Google tag. It was Analytics. And 0 errors.

Bottomline, everything - even Google extension - says nothing wrong. But still not tracking.

**EDIT: Did not change anything, did not do anything. Code works now. Seems sometimes 24 hours is not enough. For me, code worked after 30 hours.**

Comment: seems you didn't check edit

Answer (score 0):

After you have installed the tracking code, you will need to wait at least 24 hours for stats to show up in your standard reports. What you can do is to check in Real-time reports to see if you see hits for you own simultaneous visits. If you see data there, then you should only need to wait the aforementioned 24 hours.

Comment: "Bottomline, everything - even Google extension - says nothing wrong. But still not tracking." anyway problem solved after 30 hours

Comment: Yeah, that's just as I thought. :)
There won't be any real indication about problems, other than what you see in Google Analytics, even through debugging tools, and as usual with Google, just need to have some patience.